# What do you use to generate and manage your rockspec files?

Tags: lua, luarocks

When you create a new rockspec file using `luarocks new_version`, do most people just delete the old one using a custom script? Or are there popular luarocks modules/rocks that offer more options than just plain `luarocks new_version`?

Answer (score 1):

I use `luarocks new_version` often in conjunction with custom scripts, but I to keep the old rockspecs around too for archival purposes.